# Two borders on top of each other, are not lined up

Tags: html, css, border

Hey there guys having a really frustrating time here with CSS, basically I am trying to overlap borders with z-index to get a visual of a 1/5 border 2/5th border 3/5th border and 4/5th border of a circle

But in doing so the absolute positioned borders are not lining up exactly, you can see the color bleeding behind it, why is this? How else should I be doing this? Here is the 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/1/) and the code is below.

```css
.circle {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.two {
  border-top-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle two"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is anti-aliasing, which causes the colors to blend to prevent "jaggies" and makes it appear that the colors are bleeding. However, if you zoom in, you can see that there is no bleeding. That, and floating point numbers aren't stored exactly, so CSS's calculation of the circles is very slightly off.

I would use something like Adobe Illustrator or InkScape or even an online vector graphics tool and make an SVG of what you want.

**VERDICT:** Use something like Adobe Illustrator or InkScape or even an online vector graphics tool and make an SVG of what you want.

Comment: Even if you make the border a solid color, the red still bleeds behind the blue border https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/2/ besides in your snippet I can still see the red behind the blue. @theEpsilon

Comment: @JeffDavenport What would you like instead? Mostly blue and only a little red?

Comment: Completely blue and zero red on the blue part of the border.

Comment: @JeffDavenport Hmmm... I don't really get what you're saying. Could you draw up an example?

Comment: If you look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/6/ You can see the border is completely blue, if you look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/1/ you can see the red bleeding behind it, I want it to look like this https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/6/ with a rotated border like this https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/7/ the problem is that you can see the red behind the blue. @theEpsilon

Comment: So how would I do 1/5th border like this? without the anti-aliasing effect? https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/8/ @theEpilon

Comment: @JeffDavenport If I were you I would use something like Adobe Illustrator or InkScape or even an [online vector graphics tool](http://editor.method.ac/) and make an SVG of what you want.

Comment: Not my desired solution, but seems to be the only possible way for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.circle {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-top-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.circletwo {
  border-top-color: blue;
  z-index: 123;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circletwo"></div>
```

Comment: Not exactly try to achieve that save result using a 1/5 border like this https://jsfiddle.net/6qtLop51/9/